# How to make a grid / Fyne / Golang

Tags: go, fyne

I'm making an application with Fyne.
I need to create a grid where the left column will be fixed and the right column will stretch. In general, there will be a menu on the left, and the main block on the right (a screenshot of the expected one below).
I read the documentation https://developer.fyne.io/container/grid but still don't understand how to do it. Help me please.
[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vgym.png)

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
)

func main() {
    application := app.New()
    window := application.NewWindow("title")
    window.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1920, 1080))

    window.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the demo application of Fyne.

```
$ go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne_demo
$ fyne_demo
```

from your description here is an example with menu on the left, and the main block on the right:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()

    w := a.NewWindow("Fyne Demo")

    w.SetMaster()

    content := container.NewMax()
    title := widget.NewLabel("Component name")
    intro := widget.NewLabel("An introduction would probably go\nhere, as well as a")
    intro.Wrapping = fyne.TextWrapWord

    tutorial := container.NewBorder(
        container.NewVBox(title, widget.NewSeparator(), intro), nil, nil, nil, content)

    split := container.NewHSplit(makeNav(), tutorial)

    split.Offset = 0
    w.SetContent(split)

    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(640, 460))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}

func makeNav() fyne.CanvasObject {

    tree := widget.NewTreeWithStrings(menuItems)

    return container.NewBorder(nil, nil, nil, nil, tree)
}

var menuItems = map[string][]string{
    "":            {"welcome", "collections", "advanced"},
    "collections": {"list", "table"},
}
```

output :

[image: screen shot op the app]

if you explore their demo on your go path source you can see the full function of (makeNav) that will make things clickable.

and to make (the left column will be fixed and the right column will stretch):

```golang
split.Offset = 0
```

Comment: sorry for the intrusiveness, i changed the line `split` on `split := container.NewBorder(nil, nil, makeNavigation(), nil, tutorial)`, to make the line normal, fixed, not HSplit. How do i add a division line between blocks? And remove the separation line from the labels? https://imgur.com/lpgsoY0.png

Comment: I could create a new question, but it's better here, since the same topic

Comment: to add division add ` widget.NewSeparator()` to the side of the Border So to make divider between the menu and main block change navigation function to return `return container.NewBorder(nil, nil, nil, widget.NewSeparator(), tree)`

Comment: @headswillroll, you are welcome. but please note that in StackOverflow they don't like the thanks-only replay you may get downvoted for that. instead, you can upvote the comment or answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are making a Border layout (something attached to one edge). If so then you can set the left to be minimum size and the content stretch to fill by doing:

```golang
container.NewBorder(nil, nil, left, nil, content)
```

(the parameters are top, bottom, left, right, middle).
If you want the user to control the split then do as suggested elsewhere and user `container.NewHSplit(left, right)`.